# How to determine whether a result is notable enough?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question

With respect to publishing or pre-print, or simply discussing with other mathematicians. How can one know if a result they have found is very useful or even interesting?

For example, I have found a general solution to the Prouhet Tarry-Escott problem similar to the Thue-Morse sequence related solution with $n=R^{k-1}(k-1)!$ for $R>2$. It also has the very nice property that the disjoint multisets $A$ and $B$ satisfy $x\in A \Rightarrow$ $(x\equiv 1 \mod R)$ and $x\in B \Rightarrow$ $(x\equiv -1 \mod R)$. A simple example for $R=4$ and $k=2$ is:
$$1 + 5+5+5 = 3+3+3+7$$
$$1^{2} + 5^{2}+5^{2}+5^{2} = 3^{2}+3^{2}+3^{2}+7^{2}$$

Comment: Write the introduction section to the would-be paper. That task entails performing a literature review of all related work, summarizing what the past authors have done, and synthesizing a motivation based on *their* introduction and conclusion sections.

Comment: But, this result doesn't seem to fit any particular purpose. It's just quite neat and I find it interesting. I did read somewhere there was an open problem to find general solutions which had 'nice' patterns such as arithmetic progressions; so, in some way this result is useful. But, in general does it have to be?

Comment: I think the bottom line here is that, in basic research, "useful" and "interesting" are socially constructed descriptors whose meaning can be determined by interacting with your peers and reading their work. If you want to publish it has to be "interesting" to them—after all, they are your audience!

Comment: I believe that when one finds a particular result to be "interesting", it is at least worth writing it up as a publishable paper and submitting it to a relevant journal. In your case, perhaps the *Journal of Integer Sequences* would be a good place for this, and let the reviewer give it a read.